# Writing a portion of a file in Python

Tags: python

I have a file with information from models of this structure repeated from 1 to 100:

```
MODEL       <Number>
.....
.....
.....
ENDMDL
```

Each model has a number. The model information starts with line `MODEL <Number>` and ends with the line `ENDMDL`.

I want to write only one model model number to a new file.

Comment: I have a file with information from models. Each model have a number. The model information starts with line MODEL <Number> and ends with the line ENDMDL. I want to write only one model model number to a new file.

Comment: I edited your comment into your post. what is your exact problem? Reading your file? Extracting excactly one model? Writing a file? What code did you write?

Comment: My problem is extracting exactly one model and write it into a new file.

Comment: I wrote this:
        for node_line in node_file:
            node_line = node_line.strip()
            if not (node_line.startswith("MODEL") and  node_line.endswith(modelNr)):
                continue
            else:
                new_line += node_line
                output_model_file.write(new_line)
                if node_line == "ENDMDL":
                    output_model_file.write("TER")
                    output_model_file.close()
                    break

... but doesn't work

Comment: please do not post all importent things into comments. Edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

This code will extract all models by

- reading the whole file
- using regex to extract the modeltext and the modelnumber as tuple
- creating dictionary entries for the resulting tuples
- writing all models as single files

You can adjust it to only write one number.

Write demo data:

```
code = """MODEL       0
..0...
..0...
..0...
ENDMDL
MODEL       1
..1...
..1..
..1...
ENDMDL
"""

with open("f.txt" , "w") as w:
    w.write(code)
```

Read and parse demo data:

```
import re

with open("f.txt", "r") as r:
    allModels = r.read()

allM = {}

# the regex captures as few as possible things between 
# MODEL and ENDMDL and captures the first number after 
# MODEL as your modelnumber.

for m in re.findall(r"(MODEL\s+(\d+).+?ENDMDL)",allModels,re.DOTALL):
    # create a dictionary entry for each found match-tuple
    allM[int(m[1])] = m[0]

print(allM)

for k in allM:
    with open("model_{}.txt".format(k),"w") as w:
        w.write(allM[k])
```

Output (of the dict):

```
{0: 'MODEL       0\n..0...\n..0...\n..0...\nENDMDL', 
 1: 'MODEL       1\n..1...\n..1..\n..1...\nENDMDL'}
```